# Play Apple Music's App Songs using SystemMusic Play API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio

I have simple application through which i want to play apple music songs from my application. I have implemented this code to play & pause music from the application.

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];  
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause];
```

The issue i am facing with this implmentation:-

- I need to manually open the Apple Music App once, play the music and
  pause it before testing the app.
- The Apple music app then have instance and a song in queue to be
  played by my app.
- If i test my app with above code, it works fine for sometime but
  stops playing the songs after few iterations.

Actual requirement is just i need to run the song without starting the Apple Music app before testing my application and it should run by and when i am testing.

Please guide me that what implementation is required and can this doable or not.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/musickit/

Comment: @luk2302 Is this achievable with new Music Kit introuced in iOS 11?